# Virtual machine freezes in VMware Workstation 10

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I'm having an issue where 1 of my VM's is freezing constantly inside VMware. It's not always the same one and it doesn't seem to be related to the programs I'm running inside it.

I use the VM's to run a game called Aion (similar to WoW). The games run fine for about 1 - 2 hrs. Then suddenly one of the VM's will freeze and cause the other VM's to stop accepting input. This happens with 1, 2, or 3 VM's running. I have my log file for the specific VM's that it happened to just recently. Earlier I checked to the other log as well and they both have shown this:

**shared 5429 4915 breaks 537568 537442 inits 528737 pool 20 overflow 956**

I've tried researching it a bit but I couldn't find anything on it really. Here are my system specs as well:

```
    Operating System
        Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit SP1
    CPU
        Intel Core i5 3570K @ 3.40GHz   
        Ivy Bridge 22nm Technology
    RAM
        16.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 1066MHz (11-11-11-30)
    Motherboard
        ASRock Z77 Extreme4 (CPUSocket)
    Graphics
        2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 (EVGA)    
    Storage
        119GB Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series ATA Device (SSD 
        931GB SAMSUNG HD103SJ ATA Device (SATA) 
        465GB Seagate ST3500630AS ATA Device (SATA) 
        698GB Western Digital WD My Passport 0740 USB Device (USB)
```